# How to calculate variance explained by an environmental variable in the model?

Tags: variance, survival, deviance

I have done some survival analysis, and used the following equation to calculate variance explained by environmental variables in the survival models:

(DEV.-DEVenv)/(DEV.-DEVtime)

where DEV. is the deviance of the model assuming constant survival rates, DEVenv is the deviance of the model assuming a linear effect of an environmental variable, and DEVtime is the deviance of the model assuming time-dependent survival rates.

I should calculate variance explained by the variables temperature and salinity in the following model:

Model 1: location + temperature + salinity, deviance = 318.2

In addition, I have models

Model 2 (constant survival rate): location, deviance = 328.5
Model 3 (time-dependent survival rate): location + time, deviance = 318.7

However, if I calculate variance explained by temperature + salinity in the model 1, I get the following result:

(328.5-318.2)/(328.5-318.7) = 1.05 (i.e. more than 100%!).

Have I calculated something wrong to get this result? Should I consider temperature and salinity separately and how can one do this when both variables are in the same model?